# Database Design: Building Hours with Tenants

Tags: database-design, database-schema

I'm struggling to design a database schema that represents opening hours for buildings and their tenants. Here are the details/requirements:

Buildings:

- In general, each building's normal business hours depend on a season (summer, winter, etc.)
- Each building has different hours.
- Numerous holidays, events, etc. will override normal business hours

Tenants:

- Tenants operate within buildings, and therefore should be constrained by building hours.
- Normal hours also depend on a season, but are not the same as its building's seasonal hours.
- Each tenant has different hours

Ideally, I'd like to be able to query the following:

- Whether or not a building or tenant is open right now
- What are building hours today
- What are building hours for the next X days

My (unfinished) work so far has been these three tables, but I'm still having trouble creating a working solution.

```
[Season]
id
building_id
title
start_date
end_date

[Schedule]
id
season_id
day_of_week (0-6)
open_time
close_time

[Override]
id
schedule_id
date
is_closed
is_holiday
```

---

Thanks all for your time and input on this. All of the answers develop/refine the solution. Catcall's idea of storing the individual dates is the easiest for us to develop a model and admin/management interface for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the problem a different way. Operating hours are not essentially different for buildings and tenants. That is, the values may vary, but the idea of a building being open or not isn't essentially different from a tenant being open or not.  I created a separate schema, "hours", to play with this idea.

```
-- Essentially a supertype, but I couldn't think of a good noun to 
-- describe it.  So I named the table "x".  It holds all the attributes 
-- common to both buildings and tenants. (That is, not very much.)
--
create table hours.x (
  x_id integer primary key,
  x_name varchar(35) not null,
  x_type char(1) check (x_type in ('b','t')),
  unique (x_id, x_type)
);

insert into hours.x values 
(1, 'First building', 'b'),
(2, 'Second building', 'b'),
(3, 'First tenant', 't'),
(4, 'Second tenant', 't'),
(5, 'Third tenant', 't');

create table hours.buildings (
  bldg_id integer primary key,
  x_type char(1) not null default 'b' check (x_type = 'b'),
  foreign key (bldg_id, x_type) references hours.x (x_id, x_type),
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x'
);

insert into hours.buildings (bldg_id) values 
(1), (2);

create table hours.tenants (
  tenant_id integer primary key,
  x_type char(1) not null default 't' check (x_type = 't'),
  foreign key (tenant_id, x_type) references hours.x (x_id, x_type),
  bldg_id integer not null references hours.buildings (bldg_id),
  other_columns char(1) not null default 'x'
);

insert into hours.tenants (tenant_id, bldg_id) values
(3, 1), (4, 1), (5, 2);


-- Operating hours records a half open interval [opening_time, closing_time).
-- If a queried time matches the opening time, the building or tenant is open.
-- But if it matches the closing time, it's *not* open.  Examples later.
create table hours.op_hours (
  x_id integer not null references hours.x (x_id),
  opening_time timestamp not null,
  closing_time timestamp not null,
  check (opening_time < closing_time),
  check (
    -- Open and close on the same date,
    ( opening_time::date = closing_time::date ) or
    -- or close at midnight following the opening.
    ( 
      (opening_time::date + interval '1' day = closing_time::date) and 
      (cast(closing_time as time) = '00:00')
    )
  )
);

insert into hours.op_hours values
-- Bldg 1 is normally Mon-Sat, 9:00 to 5:00. Closed on Jan 1, holiday
(1, '2012-01-02 09:00', '2012-01-02 17:00'),
(1, '2012-01-03 09:00', '2012-01-03 17:00'),
(1, '2012-01-04 09:00', '2012-01-04 17:00'),
(1, '2012-01-05 09:00', '2012-01-05 17:00'),
(1, '2012-01-06 09:00', '2012-01-06 17:00'),
(1, '2012-01-07 09:00', '2012-01-07 17:00'),
-- Closed on Jan 8, a Sunday.
(1, '2012-01-09 09:00', '2012-01-09 17:00'),

-- Bldg 2 is normally Mon-Fri, 7:30 to midnight.
(2, '2012-01-02 07:30', '2012-01-03 00:00'),
(2, '2012-01-03 07:30', '2012-01-04 00:00'),
(2, '2012-01-04 07:30', '2012-01-05 00:00'),
(2, '2012-01-05 07:30', '2012-01-06 00:00'),
(2, '2012-01-06 07:30', '2012-01-07 00:00'),
-- Closed on Jan 7 and 8, weekend.
(2, '2012-01-09 07:30', '2012-01-10 00:00'),

-- "First" tenant is open 9:00 to noon and 1:00 to 4:00, Mon-Fri.
(3, '2012-01-02 09:00', '2012-01-02 12:00'),
(3, '2012-01-03 09:00', '2012-01-03 12:00'),
(3, '2012-01-04 09:00', '2012-01-04 12:00'),
(3, '2012-01-05 09:00', '2012-01-05 12:00'),
(3, '2012-01-06 09:00', '2012-01-06 12:00'),
(3, '2012-01-02 13:00', '2012-01-02 16:00'),
(3, '2012-01-03 13:00', '2012-01-03 16:00'),
(3, '2012-01-04 13:00', '2012-01-04 16:00'),
(3, '2012-01-05 13:00', '2012-01-05 16:00'),
(3, '2012-01-06 13:00', '2012-01-06 16:00'),

-- "Second" tenant is open when the building is open.
(4, '2012-01-02 09:00', '2012-01-02 17:00'),
(4, '2012-01-03 09:00', '2012-01-03 17:00'),
(4, '2012-01-04 09:00', '2012-01-04 17:00'),
(4, '2012-01-05 09:00', '2012-01-05 17:00'),
(4, '2012-01-06 09:00', '2012-01-06 17:00'),
(4, '2012-01-07 09:00', '2012-01-07 17:00'),
-- Closed on Jan 8, a Sunday.
(4, '2012-01-09 09:00', '2012-01-09 17:00'),

-- "Third" tenant is open Mon-Thu 7:30 to 9:30, Fri until midnight.
(5, '2012-01-02 07:30', '2012-01-02 21:30'),
(5, '2012-01-03 07:30', '2012-01-03 21:30'),
(5, '2012-01-04 07:30', '2012-01-04 21:30'),
(5, '2012-01-05 07:30', '2012-01-05 21:30'),
(5, '2012-01-06 07:30', '2012-01-07 00:00'),
-- Closed on Jan 7 and 8, weekend.
(5, '2012-01-09 07:30', '2012-01-09 21:30');
```

It should be clear that this kind of structure, which records each day's operating hours for every building and every tenant, will accommodate any definition of season, holidays, events, and so on.  Default data can be generated with a fairly simple stored procedure. And the required queries are dead simple. (There's a lot of value in being able to look at something and *see* that it's right.)

```
-- Is building 1 open at 9:00 am on Jan 3? (Queries for tenants are essentially
-- identical. Returns the id number if it's open, but that could be massaged 
-- into an "is_open" derived column with Boolean values.)
select x_id
from hours.op_hours
where x_id = 1
  and opening_time <= '2012-01-03 09:00' 
  and '2012-01-03 09:00' < closing_time;

-- How about on Jan 1? (Returns an empty set if closed. See above.)
select x_id
from hours.op_hours
where x_id = 1
  and opening_time <= '2012-01-01 09:00' 
  and '2012-01-01 09:00' < closing_time;

-- Which tenants, regardless of building, are open on Jan 4 at 9:00 am?
select op_hours.x_id
from hours.op_hours
inner join hours.tenants on hours.tenants.tenant_id = hours.op_hours.x_id 
where opening_time <= '2012-01-04 09:00' 
  and '2012-01-04 09:00' < closing_time;
```

Note that each of those queries operates on a half open interval. You can't use the BETWEEN operator, because it operates on a closed interval.

Which requirements does this structure *not* accommodate?

- Tenant operating hours must be a subset of building operating hours. Can't be done declaratively unless your dbms support assertions. Can be done with procedural code in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a pretty good start with your table design.

**Building Hours *(your model so far)***

Your `[Override]` table could be adjusted to simplify data maintenance and querying.

Assuming that your business rule is that an override is always for a (whole) single day, then you want to override at the season level, not the schedule level.  This saves you having to worry about which day of the week an override comes on.  You could generalize more easily too, by including start_date and end_date columns in your override table.  Also, your flags (`is_closed`, `is_holiday`) could be simplified to a single enumeration column (`closed_reason`).  This would allow you to add new reasons in the future without having to change your schema and queries.

**Tenant Hours *(the next step)***

Your tennant schedules model should be similar to your building hours.  Depending on how often you expect tennant hours to diverge from building hours, you could include a flag on your tennant table to indicate `uses_building_schedule`.  This would indicate that there are no tennant schedule entries.

For tennants with a schedule distinct from the building they occupy, just use the same season / schedule / override structure.

Since you have a rule that says tennant hours must be constrained by building hours, you will need to add procedural code to enforce this rule.  I would do it at query time, not at data maintenance time.  In other words, when querying for a tennant's hours, I would see if they have open hours and then restrict these open hours by the building hours.

Comment: Great suggestions under Building Hours; all of those things make sense to me. Regarding your comment on Tenant Hours, do you think I need to create three separate tables, or should I combine with building tables? For the constraints, I plan to use form validation (when entering hours) to force tenant hours to fit within building hours.

Comment: @kml - To combine schedule tables for buildings and tennants you'd have to invert the relationship (like what Branko suggested) or sub-type buildings and tennants under some new table (i.e.: `THINGS_THAT_HAVE_SCHEDULES`).  In my view that is over-complicating things a little bit.  You already have different business rules and you may very well have different columns in the future for each type of schedule.  I'd leave the two kinds of schedules separate.  It may be less "elegant" (i.e. over-engineered) but it will be easier to take care of over time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much it will fit your requirements, but let me offer an idea:

[image]

This model has following characteristics:

- A building or tenant has a schedule (that may or may not be shared with other buildings/tenants).
- A schedule is a set of intervals.
- Each interval has a priority within a schedule: intervals with higher priority "override" intervals with lower priority. Look at how SCHEDULE_ITEM is constrained so no interval can belong twice to the same schedule, and cannot have an ambiguous priority relative to other intervals belonging to the same schedule (UNIQUE constraint `U1`).
- Intervals can be shared among schedules, so for example you can setup a single interval covering an annual event, then share it among many schedules. If the event changes, you only have to update it in one place.

The problem with this model is that it's processing-heavy and DBMS will not help you avoid some nonsensical cases in your data (you'll need to do it at the application level). On the other hand, it is very flexible and powerful.

Finding hours for a building or tenant on a given day is not trivial: you need to intersect all intervals under the schedule in the order of their priority. To find hours for given tenant, you need to fist find hours for her building and then intersect them.

#### Example

A schedule that...

- has 9 AM - 5 PM hours throughout year,
- except from May to October when it has 8 AM - 6 PM,
- except on Saturday when it has 9 AM - 1 PM,
- and no hours on Sunday
- and no hours on January 1st, July 4th and December 25th

...could be represented like this:

```
SCHEDULE_ID     PRIORITY    MONTH_START     MONTH_END       DAY_OF_MONTH_START      DAY_OF_MONTH_END        DAY_OF_WEEK_START       DAY_OF_WEEK_END     HOUR_START      HOUR_END
1               1           NULL            NULL            NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                9 AM            5 PM
1               2           5               10              NULL                    NULL                    NULL                    NULL                8 AM            6 PM
1               3           NULL            NULL            NULL                    NULL                    6                       6                   9 AM            1 PM
1               4           NULL            NULL            NULL                    NULL                    7                       7                   NULL            NULL
1               5           1               1               1                       1                       NULL                    NULL                NULL            NULL
1               6           7               7               4                       4                       NULL                    NULL                NULL            NULL
1               7           12              12              25                      25                      NULL                    NULL                NULL            NULL
```